# Show that $g(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \dotsb + x^{n-1}$ is the generating polynomial for the $[n, 1]$ repetition code

Tags: cyclic-groups, coding-theory

How would I go about proving this? Would I have to find $\alpha(x)$ and multiply it by $g(x)$?

Comment: What stops you from applying the definition of a cyclic code generated by a given polynomial? Hint: Calculate $x g(x)$ modulo $x^n-1$.

Comment: The generator polynomial of a linear binary cyclic code is the (nonzero) polynomial of least degree in the set of _codeword polynomials_. So, _find_ the set of codeword polynomials (hint: there are only two codewords in a $[n,1]$ code and so only two codeword polynomials!) and you are done after a _very_ brief search.